# (Flask) how to detect client disconnect in flask sockets

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web, flask-socketio

I want to print something when a client disconnected, but this isn't working

Javascript client:

```
socket.on("connect", () => {
   
    socket.on("disconnect",  () => {
     
       socket.emit("disconnected", "{{room_num}}")

   })

})
```

Python flask :

```
@socketio.on("disconnected")
def handle_disconnect(room_num):
   print(f"user in room {room_num} disconnected")
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand. In the client, you want to emit something as a result of being disconnected? How is the emit going to work if you are disconnected?

Comment: Yes i want to emit when disconnected but i dont think its possible,  but all i need is to know the disconnected client's `{{room_num}}` variable when they disconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its impossible to emit something when disconnected to I just ended up using `request.sid` to identify different disconnected clients.